# Save PostgreSQL date with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I execute the following query, It updates the date field with time zone

```
update person set hiredate='2018-06-18 23:59:59-04:00' where id=5684
```

When I query the same as:

```
select * from person where id=5684
```

I get following value for hiredate: `2018-06-19 09:29:59` (in My timezone +5:30)

But I want to execute a query as

```
update person set hiredate=now()::date + time '23:59:59-04:00' where id=5684
```

and run the select query, I get the hiredate as: `2018-06-18 23:59:59`

Please help me how I can

Comment: Is the time zone on the server the same as yours?

Comment: are you executing the query and checking the result in the same time zone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` is short for `time without time zone`. Try

```
UPDATE person
       SET hiredate = now()::date + time with time zone '23:59:59-04:00'
       WHERE id = 5684;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want is

```
update person set hiredate= timestamp with   
time zone now()::date + time '23:59:59-04:00' 
where id=5684;
```

Comment: `time '23:59:59-04:00' ` is as same as using `time '23:59:59'` and that is not what the user probably wants.